# How do I give permissions to hidden standard objects (MetricsDataFile)?

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

I'm trying to create a permissions set so I can assign users to be able to view the Usage Metrics app. I've given access to the app, tab, apex classes, and visualforce pages. However, Users still receive an error when trying to access the app:

"System.QueryException: sObject type 'MetricsDataFile' is not supported."

The line of code that causes the error is: List results =  [SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM MetricsDataFile GROUP BY NamespacePrefix limit 25];

It seems like I need to add permissions to view the 'MetricsDataFile ' object, but I'm unable to find this object in my org. Anybody know what I should try here? What to look for?

When I go to data loader, I am only able to see this object when I click on 'Show all Salesforce objects'

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it has something to do with the Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Per Salesforce Support and verification in my company's org, the "Modify All Data" system permission is required for any access to the [MetricsDataFile object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_metricsdatafile.htm) once it is available in your org.